# Replacing values in the middle of one list from another list

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing, replace

I want to replace the values in the middle of one list with the values in the middle of another list. You know that it is in the middle if its between 0's and 1's. I want to do this preferably in the lowest big-o complexity because i want to repeat it thousands of times

```
l1 = [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,   0.3,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.6,   1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]

#l1 is a list of numbers with unique values that are not 0.0 or 1.0 in the middle

l2 = [0.0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,   0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.4,   0.5,0.5,0.6,0.6,0.7,0.7,0.8,0.8,0.9,0.9]

#I want to replace the above middle values of l1 to the middle values of l2 to get l3

l3 = [0.0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,   0.3,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.6,   0.5,0.5,0.6,0.6,0.7,0.7,0.8,0.8,0.9,0.9]

#given that I know nothing about how many middle values there are or where they are
```

edit: lists are fixed length and sorted

edit2: here is my ugly solution. Can it be improved upon?

```
stop0 = -1
stop0bool = True
stop1 = -1
for i in range(20):
  if stop0bool and l1[i] != 0.0:
    stop0 = i
    stop0bool = False
  if l1[i] == 1.0:
    stop1 = i
    break;
l3 = l2[0:stop0] + l1[stop0:stop1] + l2[stop1:20]
```

Comment: How large are you real lists? Similar size to your example or much larger? Is it ok to perform replacement in-place, or you always need to create new lists? What exactly do you have to repeat thousands of times, both finding indices and creating new lists, or you find the indices only once, and then perform replacement with the same indices for thousands of other arrays?

Comment: the real lists have lengths in the hundreds. Whatever process doesn't matter I just need a resulting list that is equal to what I stored in L3.

Comment: Are the lists always sorted? Are the lists always of the same length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For lists that have hundreds of elements [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) should give you a significant performance boost.

For the following example data:

```
import numpy as np

size = 500
x, y = 10, 486
a = np.sort(np.random.rand(size))
a[:x] = 0
a[y:] = 1
b = np.sort(np.random.rand(size))
```

using [boolean array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) with in-place replacement gives ~10x increase in speed:

```
mask = (a > 0) & (a < 1)
b[mask] = a[mask]
# 4.5 µs ± 23.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

comparing to your solution:

```
# 74 µs ± 61.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: this was the fastest solution

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.

```
l1 = [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.6,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]
l2 = [0.0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.5,0.6,0.6,0.7,0.7,0.8,0.8,0.9,0.9]

l3 = [ l2[a[0]] if a[1] in [0.0, 1.0] else a[1] for a in enumerate(l1) ]


print (l3)

#[0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9]
```

or you can use zip

```
l4 = [a[1] if a[0] in [0.0, 1.0] else a[0] for a in zip(l1,l2)]

print (l4)

#[0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9]
```

Comment: this worked but I ran it against my code and it is actually slower.

Comment: I don't know which one is faster but you can also try `zip` version.

Answer (score 1):

This implementation is about 25% faster than yours on my machine and still gives the exact same result.

```
s = None
for i,v in enumerate(l1):
    if v <= 0:
        continue  
    elif v < 1:
        if s:
            continue
        s = i
    else:
        l3 = l2[:s] + l1[s:i] + l2[i:]
        break
```